# Multipy each row of numpy array with matrix

Tags: python, numpy

What is the most pythonic way to multiply each row(axis=2) of a np array with a matrix. For example, I am working with images read as np array of shape (480, 512, 3), I want to multiply each img[i,j] with a 3x3 matrix. I don't want to use for loops for this. This is what I tried but it gives an error

```
A = np.array([
        [.412453, .35758, .180423],
        [.212671, .71516, .072169],
        [.019334, .119193, .950227]
    ])
lin_XYZ = lambda x: np.dot(A, x[::-1])
#lin_XYZ = np.vectorize(lin_XYZ)
tmp_img = lin_XYZ(tmp_img[:,:])

File ".\proj1a.py", line 24, in color2luv
tmp_img = lin_XYZ(tmp_img[:,:])
File ".\proj1a.py", line 22, in <lambda>
lin_XYZ = lambda x: np.dot(A, x)
```

> ValueError: shapes (3,3) and (480,512,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 512 (dim 1)

Comment: By "row" do you actually mean axis=2 or axis=1?  (since first axis,  the column axis, would be axis=0?)

Comment: Looks like what you want is simply `x.dot(A)` not `A.dot(x)`.

Comment: You could reshape your matrix, say, from MxNx3, to Ox3, with O = M*N, then multiply it, then reshape it again.

Comment: @AGNGazer, please reference : https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: @AGNGazer sorry I'll try to improve next time, but I am not trying to multiply (480,512) by 3x3, what I meant was each `img[i,j]` would give a row with 3 elements and then multiply it with the `3x3` matrix, I'll try to describe the problem better next time @heltonbiker I'll try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `A` is (3,3) and `x` is (480, 512, 3), and you what is a `dot` on the size 3 dimension.  The key thing to remember with `dot(A,B)` is, last dim of A with 2nd to the last of B.  (That's what the error is complaining about `3 (dim 1) != 512 (dim 1)`)

```
x.dot(A)
x.dot(A.T)
```

would meet that requirement.

```
A.dot(x.transpose(0,2,1))   #  (3,3) with (480,3,512)
```

would also work, though the resulting array may need further transposing - assuming you want the 3 to be last.

You can also pair dimensions with `einsum` or `tensordot`:

```
np.einsum('ij,kli->klj', A, x)
```

---

`x[::-1]` flips `x` on its first dimenion, the 480 one.  Shape remains the same.  Did you want the transpose?

Comment: Thank you. I'm using opencv to read the image, in (480,512,3) the 3 represents color bands - R, G, B but opencv reads it as BGR, I need it as RGB so I thought using `x[::-1]` would do that.

Comment: Sure if you need to swap color bands,then the `::-1` is right.